# $f(x)= \min\{ x-\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor ,-x-\left\lfloor -x \right\rfloor \} \quad $ for $-2 \le x \le2$

Tags: functions

[image]

If $f(x)= \min\{ x-\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor ,-x-\left\lfloor -x \right\rfloor \} \quad $ for $-2 \le x \le2$

Then  how to find number of solutions of the equation $x^2+[f(x)]^2$=$1$ 
in {$-1\le x \le 1$} ?

Comment: It seems that the solutions are $x=\pm 1$.

Comment: How did you get it ? @EmilioNovati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting form your graph, we see that the function $F(x)=[f(x)]^2$ is allways $\ge 0$ in $[-1,1]$ and $[f(x)]^2=0$ for $x=\pm1$ and $x=0$ and has maximum value $M=0.25$ in $x=\pm 0.5$.

Now you want: $x^2-1+F(x)=0$ and this is obviously true for $x=\pm 1$.

For the other values, note that the equation is symmetric, so we can work with $x>0$.

For $0\le x\le 0.5$ we have obviously $|x^2-1|<x^2=F(x)$ and for $0.5<x<1$ we have $|x^2-1|<(x-1)^2=F(x)$.

So there are not other roots.